# How to do Cascading Include in LiteDB

Tags: c#, .net, litedb, nosql

here is example on how to store cross-referenced entities in LiteDB. LiteDB stores the cross-referenced entities perfectly fine, but problem comes when I am trying to find/load entities back. My goal is NOT ONLY the requested entity but also referenced ones. There is quick tutorial section "DbRef for cross references" on LiteDB [webpage](http://www.litedb.org/) how one can realize it. LiteDB has "Include" option (which is called before "FindAll") which says which referenced entities must be loaded as well. I am trying to achieve it in this code example but with no results, i.e, the code raises Exception("D_Ref") meaning "D_Ref" reference is not loaded:

```
namespace _01_simple {
using System;
using LiteDB;

public class A {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public B B_Ref { set; get; }
}
public class B {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public C C_Ref { set; get; }
}
public class C {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public D D_Ref { set; get; }
}
public class D {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        test_01();
    }

    static string NameInDb<T>() {
        var name = typeof(T).Name + "s";
        return name;
    }

    static void test_01() {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"MyData.db"))
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"MyData.db");

        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db")) {
            var As = db.GetCollection<A>(NameInDb<A>());
            var Bs = db.GetCollection<B>(NameInDb<B>());
            var Cs = db.GetCollection<C>(NameInDb<C>());
            var Ds = db.GetCollection<D>(NameInDb<D>());

            LiteDB.BsonMapper.Global.Entity<A>().DbRef(x => x.B_Ref, NameInDb<B>());
            LiteDB.BsonMapper.Global.Entity<B>().DbRef(x => x.C_Ref, NameInDb<C>());
            LiteDB.BsonMapper.Global.Entity<C>().DbRef(x => x.D_Ref, NameInDb<D>());

            var d = new D { Name = "I am D." };
            var c = new C { Name = "I am C.", D_Ref = d };
            var b = new B { Name = "I am B.", C_Ref = c };
            var a = new A { Name = "I am A.", B_Ref = b };

            Ds.Insert(d);
            Cs.Insert(c);
            Bs.Insert(b);
            As.Insert(a);
        }

        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db")) {
            var As = db.GetCollection<A>(NameInDb<A>());

            var all_a = As
                .Include(x => x.B_Ref)
                .FindAll();
            foreach (var a in all_a) {
                if (a.B_Ref == null)
                    throw new Exception("B_Ref");
                if (a.B_Ref.C_Ref == null)
                    throw new Exception("C_Ref");
                if (a.B_Ref.C_Ref.D_Ref == null)
                    throw new Exception("D_Ref");
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after small research I've resolved the issue simply by adding extra "Include" parameterize by "x => x.B_Ref.C_Ref" lambda where x.B_Ref.C_Ref is a path in hierarchy of references:

```
var all_a = As
    .Include(x => x.B_Ref)
    .Include(x => x.B_Ref.C_Ref)
    .FindAll();
```

Here is complete example

```
namespace _01_simple {
using System;
using LiteDB;

public class A {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public B B_Ref { set; get; }
}
public class B {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public C C_Ref { set; get; }
}
public class C {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public D D_Ref { set; get; }
}
public class D {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        test_01();
    }

    static string NameInDb<T>() {
        var name = typeof(T).Name + "s";
        return name;
    }

    static void test_01() {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"MyData.db"))
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"MyData.db");

        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db")) {
            var As = db.GetCollection<A>(NameInDb<A>());
            var Bs = db.GetCollection<B>(NameInDb<B>());
            var Cs = db.GetCollection<C>(NameInDb<C>());
            var Ds = db.GetCollection<D>(NameInDb<D>());

            LiteDB.BsonMapper.Global.Entity<A>().DbRef(x => x.B_Ref, NameInDb<B>());
            LiteDB.BsonMapper.Global.Entity<B>().DbRef(x => x.C_Ref, NameInDb<C>());
            LiteDB.BsonMapper.Global.Entity<C>().DbRef(x => x.D_Ref, NameInDb<D>());

            var d = new D { Name = "I am D." };
            var c = new C { Name = "I am C.", D_Ref = d };
            var b = new B { Name = "I am B.", C_Ref = c };
            var a = new A { Name = "I am A.", B_Ref = b };

            Ds.Insert(d);
            Cs.Insert(c);
            Bs.Insert(b);
            As.Insert(a);
        }

        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db")) {
            var As = db.GetCollection<A>(NameInDb<A>());

            var all_a = As
                .Include(x => x.B_Ref)
                .Include(x => x.B_Ref.C_Ref)
                .Include(x => x.B_Ref.C_Ref.D_Ref)
                .FindAll();
            foreach (var a in all_a) {
                if (a.B_Ref == null)
                    throw new Exception("B_Ref");
                if (a.B_Ref.C_Ref == null)
                    throw new Exception("C_Ref");
                if (a.B_Ref.C_Ref.D_Ref == null)
                    throw new Exception("D_Ref");
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

I hope it saves someone's time.

Update: LiteDB author says there is no support for Cascading Include. But it is planned in the next version (see [issue](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/322)). Consider, once, let say, B_Ref is a Lite of B, then there is no mechanism to force deeper Include.

Comment: Now you can use deep includes in v4 using `BsonExpression`. Use string expressions like "$.Customer", "$.Customer.Address" or linq `x => x.Customer`. https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/DbRef